# What's the difference between Array(2) and [undefined, undefined]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined].map(function(val, i) { return i });
```

returns [0, 1, 2], while

```
Array(3).map(function(val, i) { return i });
```

returns [undefined, undefined, undefined].

Why?

Answer (score 13):

In the first case you've *defined* and ***initialized*** a new array with three `undefined` values, whereas in the second case you've *only* ***defined*** an array with *possible* length of 3.

`new Array(3)` is the same as you do:

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = 3;
```

As a result, having `.length` property implicitly defined, `.map()` method can do the iteration over the array allocated in memory, which basically holds zero defined items (i.e. purely empty).

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring pointers to undefined objects writing `undefined`.  Thus, `[undefined]` creates an array of a pointer to undefined.  `new Array(3)` creates an array of *undefined pointers*, which are not looped over by array prototype methods (including `.map`).

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description).  The variable `undefined` is actually assigning a value even though it points to `undefined`.

Comment: So you mean Array(1)[0] is a differrent value internally than [undefined][0]?

Comment: @Matt no, I believe that they dereference the same.

Comment: Its not a different value. The second one has a reference to the value `undefined` because the global Objects `undefined` property is initially set to the value `undefined` therefore referencing to `undefined` wheras `Array(1)` has an undefined reference. Which evaluates to the same value `undefined` so `Array(1)[0] === [undefined][0] //true` like `var undefined2;new Array(1)[0] === [undefined2][0]` where `undefined2` contains a reference to the value `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`Array(3)` just takes an empty array and manually assigns it a length:

```
> a = []
[]
> a.length = 3
3
> a
[ , ,  ]
```

Which is not the same thing as manually constructing an array containing undefined elements:

```
> a = [undefined, undefined, undefined]
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

---

The [MDN documentation for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) explains exactly what is going on:

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (inclusive), a new, empty JavaScript array and its length is set to that number. If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

So the array is initialized to an empty array `[]`. This explains why `map` does not process any of the array elements, because there are none.

---

A few examples may help. When the array is initialized using `Array(3)` it is empty so `map` has nothing to iterate over:

```
> Array(3)
    .map(function(val, i) { console.log(i); return i; });
[ , ,  ]
```

Compare that with the following example, where you can see that each intermediate array value is output to the console:

```
> [undefined, undefined, undefined]
    .map(function(val, i) { console.log(i); return i; });
0
1
2
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855791/1742381) mentioned, Array(3) is **defined** but **uninitialized**. Interestingly, you can pass the uninitialized array through Array.apply, and initialize it. I've used this to fill arrays:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map(function(val,i) { return i; });
// [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 test();
 test2();

function test() {
   [undefined, undefined, undefined].map(function(val, i) { console.log("un: " + val + "/" + i); return i; });
 }

 function test2() {
    Array(3).map(function(val, i) { console.log("no: " + val + "/" + i); return i; });
 }
</script>
```

**test() function returns:**

un: undefined/0
un: undefined/1
un: undefined/2

**test2() function does not return a value;**

- test() you have an object with that contains 3 values (undefined)
- test2() has an empty array of length 3